# Is it possible to embed a Blob URL image in GitHub Markdown?

Tags: image, github, markdown, blob

I want to embed a Blob URL image in my GitHub `README.md` file. When I tried `![image](blob:https://{...})` it failed. Is it possible to embed this format in Markdown file?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately github doesnt allow either blob or data uri's as image source.

source : https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#images